# How to make authentication for zendesk using reactjs application having auth0 login

Tags: reactjs, auth0, zendesk

I am new to zendesk, I need to integrate zendesk in my reactjs application.

I have reactjs application. I am using auth0 for authentication. Now I need to authenticate zendesk with my reactjs application.

Is it possible to authenticate zendesk using auth0 login system.
Example: zillow.com (I need same as zillow website)

Answer (score 0):

The trick for single-sign-on is to make all applications (in this case your React app and Zendesk) use the same external identity provider. Each application is unaware of others. When the user logs in for the first time in the identity provider a session is established, so the next application that asks for an authentication can receive an immediate response without the user having to log in again.
Something like this:

1. The user goes to your React app.
2. The user doesn't have a session in the app. The app redirects the user to Auth0 for an authentication.
3. The user has no session in Auth0, so she's asked to authenticate.
4. Auth0, after identifying the user, create a session for her. Then it sends a response back to your React app.
5. Now the user navigates to Zendesk.
6. Zendesk sees no session for the user. Redirects to Auth0 (the common identity provider) to authenticate the user.
7. Auth0 now sees a valid session. It returns an authentication response to Zendesk without prompting the user (depending on the protocol there might be a consent prompt the first time).
8. Zendesk receives the response from Auth0 and creates a session for the user.

This concept applies to any type of application. To integrate Zendesk so that Auth0 is the identity provider, you have a pre-configured solution under "SSO Integrations". Check https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/sso/zendesk for detailed instructions.

In order for this to work in Auth0 make sure that the same connections are enabled for both your React application and the Zendesk SSO integration.

Comment: Hi Nico Sabena, Thanks for reply, I understand the process flow. But I am confused at how the user authenticate from zendesk after getting session from auth0 in my reactjs application.